# how i can get textarea id

Tags: javascript, html, textarea

I have three textarea and each name is like id1,id2,id3 and i want to store id of textarea in which i type something.for emample if i write something in second text area so id of second text area will be store in my variable.is it possible if yes then how.please help! Basically i am working text counter task where i have n number of multiple textarea wherer there id is generating dynamically and i have to count of each text when user type in the textarea.i am trying to write logic where user click on which textarea that textarea count is only increase.

I have written the code to count text of textarea but it only working for the new textarea if user switching to previous text area the text counter is not working for current textarea.it is working for previous textarea because preavoius textarea id is stored into the variable.i want to work on the current textarea in which i type something.

herer is my code

```
 $('#विवरण_'+startvalue).on("input", function() {
     
        var सीमा = $(this).attr("maxlength");
        var संख्या = $(this).val().length;

        if (संख्या >= सीमा) {
            $("#अक्षर-गणक").addClass('text-danger');
            $("#अक्षर-गणक").removeClass('text-muted');
        } else {
            $("#अक्षर-गणक").addClass('text-muted');
            $("#अक्षर-गणक").removeClass('text-danger');
        }

        $('#संख्या_'+startvalue).text(संख्या);
    });
```

herer => '#विवरण_'+startvalue  is a id name which is genereating dynamically. and '#संख्या_'+startvalue => is a span id name where i am showing text count number.
anyone can please help.

Comment: This will depend on how `startvalue` is generated.  On its own, this code looks fine if `startvalue="text1"` (for example).  *But* as soon as you put it in a loop then the `startvalue` at the time of `on("input"` will be *different* from the `startvalue` at time of `.text()`.  I suggest linking them differently and remove `startvalue` *completely*.   Provide some HTML with at least two text areas + counts `संख्या_`.  Please also confirm that there's only one `id=अक्षर-गणक`

Comment: actually i have define  var startvalue = 1; regarding to id .

Answer (score 1):

You can use `this` keyword inside the event listener. this refers to the element that triggered the event, which in this case is the `textarea`. You can then use the `attr()` method to get the `ID` attribute of the textarea and store it in a variable for later use:

```js
$('textarea').on("input", function() {
    var textareaId = $(this).attr('id');
    console.log(textareaId);
    var सीमा = $(this).attr("maxlength");
    var संख्या = $(this).val().length;

    if (संख्या >= सीमा) {
        $("#" + textareaId + "_count").addClass('text-danger');
        $("#" + textareaId + "_count").removeClass('text-muted');
    } else {
        $("#" + textareaId + "_count").addClass('text-muted');
        $("#" + textareaId + "_count").removeClass('text-danger');
    }

    $('#' + textareaId + '_count').text(संख्या);
});
```

```css
.text-danger {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="id1" maxlength="2"></textarea>
<span id="id1_count"></span>

<textarea id="id2" maxlength="5"></textarea>
<span id="id2_count"></span>

<textarea id="id3" maxlength="10"></textarea>
<span id="id3_count"></span>
```